# Converter for Media – Optimize images | Convert WebP & AVIF

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to configure the Converter for Media plugin that supports the WebP and AVIF format. I need your help in adding the required rules to the Nginx configuration of my website - http://34.96.205.109. You can find more information in the plugin.

FAQ: https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-converter-for-media/faq/ (in the question: Configuration for Nginx)

guide me i serched everyware on google  &youtube

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the nginx conf for the website from '/etc/nginx/conf.d/web.site.ssl.conf'

Add the block of code they gave before 'location'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).